# Why should i use a predicate as a return type instead of a boolean?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just found out about user defined typeguards while reading this article: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

In one of the examples in this article they use `pet is Fish` as a method return type which is a predicate.

I found out that instead of this return type one can just as well use `boolean`. So is the `parameter is Type` returntype just syntactic sugar or does it have a specific use?

Comment: the specific use is explained in the link.  If you that type check on a variable of unknown type and it evaluates true, then typescript knows that variable is a fish and you can treat is as such safely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return a `boolean` the function will be a simple function that is not a typeguard. The `pet is Fish` syntax is what signals to the compiler that this function will impact the type of the argument.

For example :

```
class Fish { f: boolean }
class Dog { d: boolean; }

declare let x: Fish | Dog;
declare function isFish(p: Fish | Dog): boolean
declare function isFishGuard(p: Fish | Dog): p is Fish;

if (isFishGuard(x)) {
    x.f // x is Fish
}

if (isFish(x)) {
    x.f // error x is still Fish|Dog
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Fish%20%7B%20f%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20%7B%20d%3A%20boolean%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20x%3A%20Fish%20%7C%20Dog%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20isFish(p%3A%20Fish%20%7C%20Dog)%3A%20boolean%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20isFishGuard(p%3A%20Fish%20%7C%20Dog)%3A%20p%20is%20Fish%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isFishGuard(x))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x.f%20%2F%2F%20x%20is%20Fish%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isFish(x))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x.f%20%2F%2F%20error%20x%20is%20still%20Fish%7CDog%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: why does the second `if` give an error according to you? I've noticed that when you declare a variable as `type1 | type2` the variable gets the properties of both type1 and type2, meaning it is not necessary to cast the variable to either one of the 2 types after having determined the actual type via the typeguard.  So the `x.f` in the second if in your example would only return the value `undefined` if the actual type of x was not fish.

Comment: @Maurice `type1 | type2` is a union type meaning it can be either `type1` or `type2`. Typescript will only let you access common properties of such a type (in this case there are no common properties). `type1 & type2` is an intersection type and would allow access to properties of both types. The type guard is meant to narrow a union type (in this case `Fish | Dog`) to something more specific (in this case `isFishGuard` will narrow the type of `x` to `Fish`)

Comment: Please look at the code snippet i have posted under `EDIT:`. This runs without errors. AdvancedFilter and HTMLInputElement do not both have a property called `value` only HTMLInputElement has this, yet in the `else` part i can still call `filter.value` without having to cast `filter` to `HTMLInputElement` first.

Comment: @Maurice without the definitions of `isAdvancedFilter` and `AdvancedFilter` it's hard to tell what is happening. You can try my sample in the playground and you will get and error on the second access. I'll add a playground link to the answer.

Comment: nevermind, i've removed the edit from the post because you are right. While the class `AdvancedFilter` doesnt declare a `value` member this class does inherit all members from the superclass `object/any`. That class does happen to have a `value` member which explains why i'm not getting a runtime error when using this member without casting to `HTMLInputElement` first.